# Elasticsearch C# NEST IndexMany Children

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, indexing, parent-child, nest

I'm having an issue using the **bulk method** in NEST to **index child records** into Elasticsearch.

I am using ElasticSearch 2.3.5 and NEST 2.4.4

I've mapped an index as such:

```
    myindex
    {
     "mappings": {
       "elasticparent": {},
        "elasticchild": {
          "_parent": {
            "type": elasticparent
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And I've indexed the parent objects using the **IndexMany** method:

```
    client.IndexMany<elasticparent>(batch, "myindex");
```

This all works well.

I would now like to index the children using **IndexMany**.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
     client.Bulk(s => s.IndexMany(IenumerableOfChild,
                                  (bulkDescriptor, record) =>
                                  bulkDescriptor.Index("myindex").Type("elasticchild").Parent(record.Id)));
```

The child and parent share the same Id integer.

I don't get an error, but the children never get indexed and the documents are never added to the total indexed count.

**Indexing them individually works**:

```
    foreach (var child in IenumerableOfChild
            {

                client.Index(child, descriptor => descriptor
                 .Parent(child.Id.ToString()).Index("myindex"));
            }
```

I don't want to index mass amounts individually.  I would like to use IndexMany to bulk index the child records.  Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After further investigation, the Elastic Server was returning a timeout.  By batching the requests to 1000 items at a time, it is now working properly!

```
    foreach (IEnumerable<object> batch in objects.Batch(1000))
            {
                var indexResponse = client.Bulk(s => s.IndexMany(batch,
                                         (bulkDescriptor, record) =>
                                           bulkDescriptor.Index("myindex").Parent(record.Id.ToString()).Document(record).Type("elasticchild").Id(record.Id.ToString())));

                Console.WriteLine(indexResponse);
            }
```

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of it. Have a play with the batch size and the number of concurrent batch requests that you can send for your cluster too.

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't thought of concurrent requests.  That's a really good idea.  Possibly a bulk async?

Comment: There's a task based `BulkAsync` method already so you can use a collection of them to fire off concurrent bulk requests. Take a look at the `BulkAll` in `master` for some ideas of how to achieve this - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/52541d0a472b6be85f5fe5d966374655671a3d37/src/Nest/Document/Multiple/BulkAll/ElasticClient-BulkAll.cs. Here's the PR for it too that has some discussion of the issue: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/2162

Answer (score 1):

You need to add. The routing field to the query in order to map the child with parent.
Like this below:-

```
var indexResponse = elasticService.Bulk(s => s.IndexMany<Child> 
                                      (childreslist, 
 (bulkDescriptor, record) => bulkDescriptor.Index(Constants.INDEX_NAME)
                                                                    .Type("_doc")
                                                                    .Routing(new 
            Routing(record.id.ToString()))
                                                                ));
```